# Asus Xtion Pro Live and PyOpenni RGB

Tags: python, kinect, openni, asus-xtion

I am using PyOpenni in python to read data sensor from an Asus Xtion Live Pro.
All works like a charm if I try to read depth data:

```
depth = DepthGenerator()
depth.create(context)
depth.set_resolution_preset(DefResolution.RES_VGA)
depth.fps = 30
context.start_generating_all()

while True:
     context.wait_one_update_all(depth)
     print depth.get_raw_depth_map_8()
```

This works fine even at 20-30 frame per second, but the problem is when I try to get the RGBImage with the same method:

```
image = ImageGenerator()
image.create(context)
image.set_resolution_preset(DefResolution.RES_VGA)
image.fps = 30
context.start_generating_all()

while True:
     context.wait_one_update_all(image)
     print image.get_raw_image_map)
```

The program waits a lot stopped in the instruction

```
 context.wait_one_update_all(image)
```

So I can get only, more or less, 2-3 frame per second.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use: `context.wait_any_update_all()` ? (takes no parameters)